# I purchased refurb. desktop with windows 10 upgrade from 7, cant connect to network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I purchased a refurbished HP desktop which had been upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10 home.  The desktop sees the wifi router, but says cant connect to network.  I have uninstalled/installed drivers, checked settings, restarted, and verified the password until I could scream.  The tech support at the seller has been unable to help me so far.  My network adapter card is 802.11n, the encryption matches the router (Linksys E3500).  Any suggestions? (Short of returning it, I really like it in all other aspects.)

Comment: I purchased this in June 2017 - there shouldn't be any windows 10 problems left!

Comment: Have you checked the router settings? MAC Address Filtering, ...

Comment: Your problems are likely not because odd windows 10 your OS is immaterial to your current problem.  It would only be a problem if your attempting to use an adapter that only supports Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

A few things you might try:

1. Since it *can* see the router, temporarily reset the router to its lowest security settings, e.g. WEP rather than WPA2, hidden network name etc. Once you can connect, revert to higher security.
2. [Download the latest Windows 10 ISO image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), put it on a USB drive, and use it to update and/or repair Windows. The reinstallation process often fixes such issues.
3. Get a [USB WiFi adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY), available for ~$US8 or less. The example shown is PnP, so Windows 10 theoretically has the correct driver. If it needs to install it from the Internet, you may need to use an Ethernet connection for your desktop, temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got connected.  The problem was that although the adapter was working properly and the computer was seeing the networks, the computer did not recognize the adapter.  bought a different usb adapter that came with an installation disk (net gear) and followed their support instructions.  It took an extra download, but it works.